# PowerApps - Hide a button after it gets clicked Once

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am trying to Hide a button after it's clicked once.  I'm Modifying a SharePoint form in PowerApps, and I need my Submit button to disappear after it's clicked One Time.

Basically, I only want this button visible for it's initial submission, but not after.  Is there a way I can hide this button after one click?  The button floats around the form if you scroll, so I want to hide it, rather than disabling it.

Basically the button's OnSelect would Submit the form, but also Hide the Button.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: do you want to hide the submit button from Edit / View form and show only for new item form? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerApps forms have three modes: New, Edit and View.

If I understand your post correctly, you only want the button to be visible when it's in New Form mode?

In that case, set the button's visible property to

> *FormName*.Mode = 1

0 = Edit

1 = New

2 = View

Comment: This worked great!  Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

Set one variable in `App.OnStart`:

```
Set(showButton, true)
```

Set `Visible` property of button to:

```
showButton
```

Then you can set the variable to false on button click (`OnSelect` property) after your logic. For example:

```
SubmitForm(Form1); Set(showButton, false)
```

---

If you want to show the button only on "New" form of list and hide it from both view/display and edit form, you can set `Visible` property of button to:

```
Form1.Mode = FormMode.New
```

Comment: but this will cause button to reappear when he again open the app. I think he wants to disappear completely.

Comment: Let us clarify what OP wants, I have added the comment above for this

Comment: Saira is correct.  This s approach works until the workflows run it seems.  I have a workflow that kicks out an email once submitted - that email contains a Link to the Item.  When I click that link, the button reappears.  I want the button to completely disappear on the form after it's clicked once.

Comment: Do you want to show the button only when new form is opened (when you click on "New" button in list? Do you use "Edit" functionality in your app? Do you need the submit button to visible again on "Edit" form OR it should be hidden on both view and edit form?

Comment: I wanted the button hidden in the form after one click.  So yes, I only want it displaying when New Item is clicked.  Managers use the link in their email notifications to navigate back to the form and edit it with approve/not approve, and comments.  I want them to click the Save button at the top left, rather than use the button.  Figured it would be less confusing to them if the button just didn't display, rather than just disabling it.

Comment: In that case, try using `Form1.Mode = FormMode.New` on Visible property of button control.